# how to work with sencha Php

Tags: sencha-touch, jsonp, extjs

I am new in Sencha 
i have created

```
var genres = new Ext.data.Store({   autoLoad: true, 
            proxy: {
                url: '../www/App/stores/genres.php'
                ,callbackKey: "callback"
                , type:'ajax',
                 reader:{
                        type:'json',
                        root:'rows'
                 }, 
                 callback:function(data){
                 alert(data);}
            },
            fields:[{name:'ii',type: 'int'},{name:'genre_name',type:'string'   }]
            });
```

the php  file creates json file but i can't  access them if i create json file instead it works fine  what to do ? help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you implement the callback on the php server properly? Like so:

```
$callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];

// Create the output object.
$output = array('a' => 'Apple', 'b' => 'Banana');

//start output
if ($callback) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($output) . ');';
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```